# How to wrap any function/curver around a circle?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebra, computational-geometry

I have a function defined as $y=f(x)$ which i want to wrap around a circle, to get a transformed function $r=f(ϕ)$. It is important that the length of the wrapped curve stay's the same. For two ϕ values the corresponding $x$ values are known. 
For the function $y=f(x)$ i already created a function to calculate the length for a give $x$ value: $s=fs(x)$.

I've tried to figure it out myself, but got stuck. Can someone help me along?

Michiel

Comment: I don't think this is about Mathematica the software, but about the underlying math. It might be a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi @Michiel Cnossen, Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
To increase the chance of good answers, it's helpful if you can edit your question and add a specific example of your problem in Mathematica code. It's easier to go from there than from an abstract/general problem.

Comment: Yes you are right MarcoB, made a mistake and posted it in the wrong place. I'll create a new question in math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved easily using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html): (note that this is also easy to do manually)

```
DSolve[{
  Norm@D[{x, f[x]}, x] ==  Norm@D[{Cos[ϕ[x]] f[x], Sin[ϕ[x]] f[x]}, x] // ComplexExpand,
    ϕ[x0] == ϕ0
  },
 ϕ[x],
 x
 ]

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.*)
```

$$\left\{\left\{\phi (x)\to \int_1^x -\frac{1}{f(K[1])} \, dK[1]-\int_1^{\text{x0}} -\frac{1}{f(K[1])} \, dK[1]+\text{$\phi $0}\right\},\left\{\phi (x)\to \int_1^x \frac{1}{f(K[2])} \, dK[2]-\int_1^{\text{x0}} \frac{1}{f(K[2])} \, dK[2]+\text{$\phi $0}\right\}\right\}$$

Essentially, we demand that the change in path length is the same for the graph of $f(x)$ (given by $(x,f(x))$) and for $(\cos\phi(x)f(x),\sin\phi(x)f(x))$. The resulting differential equation is then solved using `DSolve`.